# Apache Payara Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, devops, payara

I have an Apache reverse proxy which forwards everything to Payara. It works, but my question is how can I make the context-roots (applications) forwarding dynamic?

This is the initial configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

With the above, a call to www.example.com will return Payara's index.html, but a call to www.example.com/myapp does not work, Payara returns 404 (/myapp is an application deployed on Payara).

In order for www.example.com/myapp to work, apparently, I need to specify the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ProxyPass /myapp http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this the way it should be? Isn't there a configuration to automatically route any context-root? Editing Apache's config file every time  I deploy a new application seems rather inconvenient.

I did try using `*` when declaring `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` (i.e. `/*`) but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried ProxyPassMatch?